# Cannot read property 'isStopped' of undefined [Angular2]

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, subscriber

I'm trying to use an observable for my service in Angular 2.

But I'm receiving this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isStopped' of undefined
```

A sneak peek of my service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class Service{

  getList(){
    return new Observable((observer)=>{
      observer.next(result);
    })
  }

}
```

And the implementation:

```
import ...

@Component({...})

export class List implements OnInit {
  list : any[];
  list$ : Observable<Array<any>>;

  constructor(...){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.list$ = this.Service.getList();
    this.list$.subscribe(
      (items) => {
        this.list = items;
        console.log("triggered");
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.error(error);
      },
      ()=>{
        console.log("completed");
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Did anyone had this error? I couldn't find anything related.

================================================================

EDIT:

Sorry this is where the "isStopped" is coming from:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts#L94

From the rxjs library.

Comment: where is "isStopped" in the posted code ?

Comment: Sorry this is where the "isStopped" is coming from: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts#L94

From the rxjs library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was using a callback as a parameter inside the observable at certain point and removing that fixed the problem. I still don't understand why but I'm guessing it has to do something with how Observables work.

Answer (score 10):

To add more clarity to this problem, I've provided [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darrensapalo/1cktaL0j/26/) that demonstrates and explains the problem.

### Problematic code

The following will throw the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isStopped' of undefined.

```
somePromise
  .then(result => {
    subscriber.next(result);
    subscriber.complete();
  })
  .catch(subscriber.error);
```

### Correct code

To retain the proper scope that is expected of the `subscriber.error` method of the subscriber object, you must create an anonymous function:

```
  somePromise
  .then(result => {
    subscriber.next(result);
    subscriber.complete();
  })
  .catch((error) => subscriber.error(error));
```

A Typescript example is demonstrated in the JS section of this JS Fiddle.

#### Further readings

[You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures)